# Do VimScript functions have to start with a capital letter and if so, why?

Tags: vimscript

Is there a good reason why VimScript functions that I put in my `.vimrc` or `_vimrc` have to begin with a capital letter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To quote [`:help user-functions`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#user-functions)

> The function name must start with an uppercase letter, to avoid confusion with
>   builtin functions.

The same restriction is placed on user-defined commands, although there are a few builtin commands (`:N[ext]`, `:P[rint]`, `:X`) which start with capital letters.

Comment: Ah! It all makes sense now.  But how annoying to a former Java programmer, and to restate the command in the middle, `:P` oh well...now at least I have a reason why this is the case.

Comment: But there is more! you can use a lowercase function name you just need to prefix it with `s:` making it a script specific function. See `:h local-functions`. You can also use autoload functions which don't have this requirement. See `:h autoload-functions`.

Answer (score 5):

Old style public function names do indeed have to start with a capital letter. However script function names `s:getSNR()`, or autoloaded function names (`lh#option#get()`) do not -- I do it more and more often in my plugins.